# Activerecord create method sometimes doesn't work in time

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rspec

I'm having issues with the following code, where it only passes some of the time when I run it.

```
require_relative 'spec_helper'
require 'pry'

RSpec.describe Round do
  testFruit = [Fruit.create(name: "Anjou Pear", unit: "10/LB", price: 13.24), Fruit.create(name: "Anjou Bear", unit: "10/LB", price: 15.24)]

  before(:each) do |variable|
    @round = Round.new
  end

  it 'returns all fruit in the current round of ordering' do
    expect(@round.fruits).to  match_array(testFruit)
  end
  it 'lets you clear the list for the next round' do
    @round.next
    expect(@round.fruits).to match_array([])
  end
end
```

Where `@round.fruits` is defined as

```
def fruits
  Fruits.all
end
```

So I understand for `Fruits.all` has to wait for the testFruits to be persisted the database, and I'm guessing this isn't done in time?  Is there a way I can test this asynchronously with rspec, and should I be designing my tests differently to avoid this issue?

The error I get is
```
     Failure/Error: expect(@round.fruits).to  match_array(testFruit)

```
   expected collection contained:  [#<Fruit id: 53, pic: nil, description: nil, name: "Anjou Pear", unit: "10/LB", price: #<BigDecimal:2...l:206de28,'0.1524E2',18(27)>, created_at: "2016-09-27 18:18:23", updated_at: "2016-09-27 18:18:23">]
   actual collection contained:    []
```

```

Comment: move the testFruit = [...] inside the before(:each) as @testFruit = [...] and it should work, you don't create objects outside the examples or before(:each) block or the will stay on the database

Comment: So the objects created in the before(:each) blocks are deleted/won't persist in the database after a spec is run?

Comment: Yes, objects created inside a before(:each) block won't persist for the next spec. If you create something outside before(:each) (before(:all) for example), you have to delete that after your specs (with an after(:all) block) or use a database cleaner gem (like DatabaseCleaner) or you'll end up with a test database full of garbage from older runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can test this asynchronously with rspec

Yes, but I won't go into that here because it's not necessary if you write your test in a way more consistent with current best practices.

> should I be designing my tests differently to avoid this issue?

Yes, the issue here is most likely due to what is referred to as "leaking state" between tests. The ideal is that every single test should be completely isolated from each test so that you can run your tests in any order and they will have the same outcome.

The problem is the `testFruit` array that you have just sitting in scope. If this Array or the objects it creates in the database are changed, that change is leaked into the tests that come afterwards.

I suggest instead writing your tests like this:

```
RSpec.describe Round do
  let!(:round) { Round.new }
  let!(:test_fruit) do
    [
      Fruit.create(name: "Anjou Pear", unit: "10/LB", price: 13.24),
      Fruit.create(name: "Anjou Bear", unit: "10/LB", price: 15.24)
    ]
  end

  describe "#fruits" do
    it 'returns all fruit in the current round of ordering' do
      expect(round.fruits).to match_array(testFruit)
    end
  end

  describe "#next" do
    it 'lets clears the list for the next round' do
      round.next

      expect(round.fruits).to match_array([])
    end
  end
end
```

This makes use of the `let!` functionality of RSpec, which you can read about [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-5/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let). Basically, it ensures that you are getting a consistent setup between each test.

Lastly, you don't have to worry about any async issues regarding database writes; Rails will not continue until it receives a successful reply from the database that the data was indeed written.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm having trouble understanding how the leaking state is sometimes causing my tests to fail.

Comment: Sorry, I see now, I have   `config.order = :random`  in my specs_helper.

Comment: @RyderBergerud this is precisely the reason using a random test order is recommended, as it highlights leaky state in the form of intermittent failures